# How can I provide my own comparison for Sort-Object Cmdlet?

Tags: powershell

I have a list of paths. The filenames contain a version number and I want to sort the list by this number.

I tried using `List<T>.Sort` method as well as the `Sort-Object` Cmdlet but I have a problem with the syntax when using .NET and I don't know whether Sort-Object supports my needs.

`$files` conatins the paths and is of type `List<string>`. Being comfortable with C# I tried something like this:

```
$files.Sort(delegate($pathX, $pathY){
    [some code to extract version number from path, so $x,$y contains just the version number]
    $versionX = New-Object system.version($x);
    $versionY = New-Object system.version($y);
    return $versionX.CompareTo($versionY)
})
```

This fails already because of the delegate keyword, as I don't know how to provide the necessary function to the `List<T>.Sort` method in Powershell.

Then I stumbled upon the Cmdlet `Sort-Object`, but I can't figure out how to pass an equivalent of my code above to it.

Comment: Without a sample of your file names with the version numbers it's difficult to give any hints. You might use a `Where-Object` with the -match operator and a RegEx for the version number and then use the $Matches variable in the Sort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$paths = "C:\Files\File1.0.3.txt",         
         "C:\Files\File4.4.2.txt",
         "C:\Files\File2.0.0.txt",
         "C:\Files\File0.0.3.txt"

$paths |
  Sort-Object {$_ -match "(?<ver>(\d+\.){2}\d+)" | Out-Null; [Version]$matches.ver}
```

Which give this output:

```
C:\Files\File0.0.3.txt
C:\Files\File1.0.3.txt
C:\Files\File2.0.0.txt
C:\Files\File4.4.2.txt
```

Adjust the version extraction code/pattern to suit the actual path format.

**EDIT**
Based on @LotPings' comment, here is a clearer explanation of why this more complicated process is needed for the sorting:

With my original (poorly chosen) example data, a simple sort would give the expected sort order without any additional code:

```
$paths = "C:\Files\File1.0.3.txt",
         "C:\Files\File4.4.2.txt",
         "C:\Files\File2.0.0.txt",
         "C:\Files\File0.0.3.txt"

$paths | Sort-Object

C:\Files\File0.0.3.txt
C:\Files\File1.0.3.txt
C:\Files\File2.0.0.txt
C:\Files\File4.4.2.txt
```

However, this won't work for some other valid version values.  For example:

```
$paths = "C:\Files\File10.0.0.txt",         
         "C:\Files\File2.0.0.txt",
         "C:\Files\File20.0.0.txt",
         "C:\Files\File1.0.0.txt"

$paths | Sort-Object

C:\Files\File1.0.0.txt
C:\Files\File10.0.0.txt
C:\Files\File2.0.0.txt
C:\Files\File20.0.0.txt
```

Using the original code gives the correct order:

```
C:\Files\File1.0.0.txt
C:\Files\File2.0.0.txt
C:\Files\File10.0.0.txt
C:\Files\File20.0.0.txt
```

Comment: As long as major,minor,build all share the same number of places a normal sort would serve as well - so more varying demo data would clarify the usefulness of your approach (+1).

Comment: @LotPings - yes, you're right, I've updated the post with a better example.